# Dynamically changed script source not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

In html page, am changing the source of my config file. the source is getting changed but the changed source script file is not rendering.

The require config is not loading once the path is changed.

Here it is what have tried.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script id="reqScript" data-main="" src="require.js"></script>
    <script>
        var configPath = "";
        function setConfigPath(path){
            configPath = path;
            var getScriptID = document.getElementById('reqScript');
            getScriptID.setAttribute('data-main',configPath);
        }

        var hostname = window.location.host.toLowerCase();
        if(hostname.indexOf("domain1")!=-1){
            setConfigPath("domain1-config");
        }
        else{
            setConfigPath("domain2-config");
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data-main='"'+ configPath +'"'` is not valid HTML. The whole line is probably breaking because of that. Change it to `data-main=""`. It won't matter if there's no initial value in it because a value will be assigned on page load through your `if` statement

Comment: @Mark Eriksson : i tried with the approach you suggested, but the page is loading as empty, the config file is not getting loaded.

Comment: The script will be loaded once, when the browser encounters the element while loading the page. Modifying the `data-main` attribute won't make it load again.

Comment: @Barmar : any other solution for this to overcome with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the `data-main` attribute of the `<script>` tag won't make it reload the script. To load a script dynamically, you need to create a new element.

```
function setConfigPath(configPath){
    var getScriptID = document.createElement('script');
    getScriptID.setAttribute('data-main',configPath);
    getScriptID.src = 'require.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(getScriptID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that using `data-main` is equivalent to using `require` after you load RequireJS, you can just change your JavaScript to:

```
var hostname = window.location.host.toLowerCase();
var config_path;
if(hostname.indexOf("domain1")!=-1) {
    config_path = "domain1-config";
}
else {
    config_path = "domain2-config";
}
require([config_path]);
```

`data-main` is convenient when you already know right off the bat what value it should have. Otherwise, there's no benefit to contorting your code to generate a value for `data-main` client-side. Using it does not make things load faster, it is not magically synchronous.